# stack.yaml not pulling in dependency from github

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Here's the stack.yaml stanza

packages:

```
- location:
   git: https://github.com/TwitterFriends/lsh.git
   commit: 57d57f4209e56f526c0eca023907015935c26071
   extra-dep: true
```

I add the package to cabal file

get error when I try to build

```
While constructing the BuildPlan the following exceptions were encountered:

--  While attempting to add dependency,
    Could not find package lsh in known packages
```

What am I doing wrong?

Current project found here

https://github.com/TwitterFriends/twitter-friend-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is syntax. You added some extra spaces before `extra-dep`. Place this in `stack.yaml`. With this, your project builds on my machine.

```
- location:
    git: https://github.com/TwitterFriends/lsh.git
    commit: 57d57f4209e56f526c0eca023907015935c26071
  extra-dep: true
```

**UPDATE:** *(17 Dec 2017)*

Since `stack-1.6.1` syntax of adding github dependency is changed. You need to add your github dependency into `extra-deps` field. Something like this:

```
resolver: lts-9.17
packages: [.]

extra-deps:
- fmt-0.5.0.0
- git: https://github.com/TwitterFriends/lsh.git
  commit: 57d57f4209e56f526c0eca023907015935c26071
```

**UPDATE:** *(5 Dec 2019)*

In `stack-2.1.3` you can specify GitHub dependencies in `extra-deps` with even shorter syntax:

```
extra-deps:
- github: TwitterFriends/lsh
  commit: 57d57f4209e56f526c0eca023907015935c26071
```

Comment: the lsh package was commented out of the .cabal file. I removed the comment, and am faced with the same problem. Try doing a git pull to see change.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong here now. It's a mystery for me. But I noticed that you have double `packages` elements. Try remove both `packages` and add only this: http://lpaste.net/6027187186263130112 It finds `lsh` package now for me. Also don't forget to `stack clean` before, it may help sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem you're facing is due to a syntax error in the lines in your `stack.yaml` file directly preceding those you posted in the question.

When I visited your repo and checked out the whole `stack.yaml` file, I saw this:

```
resolver: lts-8.13

# User packages to be built.
# Various formats can be used as shown in the example below.
# 
packages:

# - https://example.com/foo/bar/baz-0.0.2.tar.gz
- location:
    git: https://github.com/TwitterFriends/lsh.git
    commit: 57d57f4209e56f526c0eca023907015935c26071
  extra-dep: true
```

This `packages:` line doesn't look right, especially given that later in the file you have:

```
packages:
- '.'
```

So my best guess would be that the `stack.yaml` file isn't getting parsed correctly, so it can't find the library b/c it doesn't know it should grab it from that location.